# How to put confimation box in extjs

Tags: extjs

In my UI, I have 3 buttons which are 'add','save' and 'cancel' and an Editor Grid Panel. Now if the user add or edit a record and try to save but accidentally clicked the cancel button, automatically all the records that supposed to be change and saved will remain the same.

My problem is that how can I put a confirmation box at the cancel button that it will only show if there are changes made in the records?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
            var grid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
                id: 'maingrid',
                store: store,

                cm: cm,


                width: 785.5,
                anchor: '100%',
                height: 700,

                frame: true,
                loadMask: true,
                waitMsg: 'Loading...',
                clicksToEdit: 2,
                tbar: [

                    '->',
                {
                    text: 'Add',
                    iconCls: 'add',  
                    id: 'b_add',
                    disabled: true,                        
                    handler : function(){          
                        var Put = grid.getStore().recordType;
                        var p = new Put({  
                            action_take: 'add',
                            is_active: '',
                            allowBlank: false
                        });
                        Ext.getCmp('b_save').enable();
                        Ext.getCmp('b_cancel').enable();
                        grid.stopEditing();
                        store.insert(0, p);
                        grid.startEditing(0, 1);                        
                        }

                },'-',{
                    text: 'Save',
                    iconCls: 'save',
                    id: 'b_save',
                    disabled: true,
                    handler : function(){
                        var objectStore = Ext.getCmp("maingrid").getStore();
                        var objectModified = objectStore.getModifiedRecords();
                        // console.log(objectModified);
                         var customer_id = Ext.getCmp("maingrid").getStore().baseParams['customer_id'];
                         var objectData = new Array();
                         var dont_include;
                         if(objectModified.length > 0)
                         {
                            for(var i = 0; i < objectModified.length; i++)
                            {
                                dont_include = false;                                   

                                    //all fields are null, then prompt that it should be filled-in (for edit)
                                    if(objectModified[i].data.id                                            
                                        &&
                                        (
                                        (objectModified[i].data.firstname == undefined || objectModified[i].data.firstname == null|| objectModified[i].data.firstname == '')
                                        ||
                                        (objectModified[i].data.lastname == undefined || objectModified[i].data.lastname == null|| objectModified[i].data.lastname == '')
                                        ||
                                        (objectModified[i].data.email_address == undefined || objectModified[i].data.email_address == null|| objectModified[i].data.email_address == '')
                                        )
                                    )
                                    {
                                        Ext.Msg.show({
                                           title: 'Warning',
                                           msg: "Input value required.",
                                           icon: Ext.Msg.WARNING,
                                           buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                                        });

                                        return;                                      
                                    }
                                     else//no id, means new record
                                     {
                                        //all fields are not filled-in, just do nothing
                                        if((objectModified[i].data.firstname == undefined || objectModified[i].data.firstname == null|| objectModified[i].data.firstname == '')&&
                                        (objectModified[i].data.lastname == undefined || objectModified[i].data.lastname == null|| objectModified[i].data.lastname == '')&&
                                        (objectModified[i].data.email_address == undefined || objectModified[i].data.email_address == null|| objectModified[i].data.email_address == ''))
                                        {
                                            //boolean flag to determine whether to include this in submission
                                            dont_include = true; 
                                        }
                                        //either one field is not filled-in prompt to fill in all fields
                                        else if((objectModified[i].data.firstname == undefined || objectModified[i].data.firstname == null|| objectModified[i].data.firstname == '')||
                                        (objectModified[i].data.lastname == undefined || objectModified[i].data.lastname == null|| objectModified[i].data.lastname == '')||
                                        (objectModified[i].data.email_address == undefined || objectModified[i].data.email_address == null|| objectModified[i].data.email_address == ''))
                                        {
                                            Ext.Msg.show({
                                               title: 'Warning',
                                               msg: "Input value required.",
                                               icon: Ext.Msg.WARNING,
                                               buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                                            });

                                            return;
                                        }

                                     }

                                     //the data for submission
                                     if(!dont_include)
                                     {
                                         objectData.push({
                                            firstname: objectModified[i].data.firstname,
                                            lastname: objectModified[i].data.lastname,
                                            email_address: objectModified[i].data.email_address,
                                            id: objectModified[i].data.id, 
                                            customer_id: customer_id

                                         });
                                     }
                            }
                           // console.log(objectData)
                            // return;

                            //check if data to submit is not empty
                            if(objectData.length < 1)//empty
                            {
                                Ext.Msg.show({
                                    title: 'Warning',
                                    msg: "No record to save",
                                    icon: Ext.Msg.WARNING,
                                    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                                });

                                Ext.getCmp('maingrid').getStore().reload();

                                return;
                            }
                            // return;
                            Ext.Msg.wait('Saving Records...');
                            Ext.Ajax.request({
                                timeout:900000,
                                params: {objdata: Ext.encode(objectData)},
                                url: '/index.php/saveContent',
                                success: function(resp){ 
                                    var response = Ext.decode(resp.responseText);
                                    Ext.Msg.hide();
                                    if(response.success == true){  
                                        Ext.Msg.show({
                                            title: "Information",
                                            msg: response.msg,
                                            buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
                                            icon: Ext.Msg.INFO,
                                            fn: function(btn){
                                                Ext.getCmp('maingrid').getStore().reload();
                                                Ext.getCmp('b_save').disable();
                                                Ext.getCmp('b_cancel').disable();

                                            }
                                        });
                                    }else{

                                        Ext.Msg.show({
                                            title: "Warning",
                                            msg: response.msg,
                                            buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
                                            icon: Ext.Msg.WARNING
                                        });
                                    }
                                },
                                failure: function(resp){  
                                    Ext.Msg.hide();
                                    Ext.Msg.show({
                                        title: "Warning1",
                                        msg: response.msg,
                                        buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
                                        icon: Ext.Msg.WARNING
                                    });
                                }
                            });


                         }
                         else{
                             Ext.Msg.show({
                                    title: 'Warning',
                                    msg: "No changes made.",
                                    icon: Ext.Msg.WARNING,
                                    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                             });

                         }  
                        }
                    },'-',
                     {
                      text: 'Cancel',
                      iconCls: 'cancel',
                      id: 'b_cancel',
                      disabled: true,

                      handler : function(){
                        Ext.getCmp('maingrid').getStore().reload();
                        Ext.getCmp('b_save').disable();
                        Ext.getCmp('b_cancel').disable();

                      }
                   }                       

            ],
            bbar: pager




    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Ext.data.Store` `getModifiedRecords()` and `getRemovedRecords()` methods to detect if grid store contains changes. For displaying confirmation dialog you can use `Ext.MessageBox.confirm()` method and then reload store only if user click on "yes" button.

```
var store = Ext.getCmp('maingrid').getStore();
var modified = store.getModifiedRecords();
var removed = store.getRemovedRecords();
if (modified.length || removed.length) {

    Ext.MessageBox.confirm('Cancel', 'Do you want cancel changes?', function(btnId) {
        if (btnId == 'yes') {
            store.reload();
            Ext.getCmp('b_save').disable();
            Ext.getCmp('b_cancel').disable();    
        }
    });
}
```